# ExtJS columns renderer, row count and setLoading

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I have a grid.Panel, it is hidden by default. When I show it, it renders 100 lines and performs the function **renderer**, but if you call **refresh()** for this table, it will render only 49 lines, what do these numbers depend on and how to change them? Also wondering if there is an event when the lines are rendered to cause **setLoading(false)**?

grid.Panel:

```js
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.commongrid',

controller: 'commongrid-controller',
viewModel: {
    type: 'commongrid-model'
},

viewConfig: {
    enableTextSelection: true
},

enableColumnMove: false,
columns: [],
bind: {
    store: '{commonDetailStore}'
},

createGrid: function (columns, data) {
    var ctrl = this.getController();

    ctrl.createGrid(columns, data);
}
```

Controller code:

```js
createGrid: function (columns, data) {
    var me = this,
        view = me.getView(),
        vm = me.getViewModel(),
        store = vm.getStore('commonDetailStore');

    columns = me.generateColumn(columns);

    view.reconfigure(columns);
    store.loadData(data);
},

generateColumn: function (columns) {
    return Ext.Array.map(columns, function (column, index) {
        return {
            'dataIndex': column,
            'text': column,
            'width': 150,
            'sortable': false,
            'resizable': true,
            'menuDisabled': true,
            'renderer': 'onCommonDetailedGridColumnRenderer'
        };
    });
}
```

grid.Model:

```js
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

alias: 'viewmodel.commongrid-model',

stores: {
    commonDetailStore: {
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage'
        },
        fields: []
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Константин Рыжков,
may you reproduce the bug in the fiddle.sencha.com?
The code you have presented a little bit strange:
In 'grid.Panel' you call a controller method 'createGrid' <- that is strange.
In the 'grid.Model' the store is defined without fields <- that is also strange.

Ext.grid.Panel.reconfigure method receives 2 params( [store], [columns] ), in your case you must write in the controller: view.reconfigure(null, columns) or view.reconfigure(store, columns);
...
...

Comment: Hello, this is not quite a bug, it’s just not clear why the first time the **column renderer** is called 100 times, and after **view.refresh()** only 49 times? And also, what event occurs after the **renderer** is no longer executed?
P.S. [Reconfigures the grid or tree with a new store and/or columns. Stores and columns may also be passed as params.](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-reconfigure)